# How to collect build info in TFS using the Artifactory NuGet Restore task?

Tags: tfs, artifactory

I'm able to restore packages without collecting build info perfectly fine. However, when I tick the 'collect build info' box, I run into the following error:

> [Error] Could not find nupkg file name for:
>   ../[ProjectName]/[ProjectName].csp

Would there be some sort of guide for this?

This is regarding JFrog Artifactory integration with TFS.

Comment: The error you're getting is caused by the fact that JFrog CLI (used by the VSTS extensions) fails when it tries to read the package dependencies from your project's project.assets.json file.
Can you please share the content of the project.assets.json file? This will help us pinpoint the issue and fix it.

Comment: You should find this file in the source code, under the obj folder.

Comment: This pull request should fix the issue: https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/pull/254/files

Answer (score 4):

This issue occurred since in the **project.assets.json** you had a reference to type **project**. We have released a new version of JFrog CLI (1.21.1) that skip dependencies of type project. When using JFrog CLI with the build-name and build-number parameters to create the build info, JFrog CLI tries to scan your project for it's dependencies. When the dependency is written as type project in the **project.assets.json**, JFrog CLI cannot gather information regarding that dependency (such as sha1, md5 and dependency nupkg file). With the latest release, JFrog CLI does not fail but skips collecting information regarding that dependency.

TFS is using behind the scene JFrog CLI. With the upcoming release of TFS plugin, the latest version of the CLI will be included. 
You can, however, update your agent with the latest JFrog CLI version that fixes this issue. You can find more information of how to use your own version of JFrog CLI in our wiki page [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/VSTS+and+TFS+Artifactory+Extension#VSTSandTFSArtifactoryExtension-InstallJFrogCLI)